# Getting lost in the code, does a better way than creating region exists?

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual c# 2010 express edition

I have nearly 1500 effective lines of code, and been using regions regularly, but it's getting out of control, how can i better organize or directly show a method, without having to click in the design form?

Edit: i've read about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx (Map dependencies) but it's for visual studio 2013, never heard of anything like it

Comment: Welcome to programming

Comment: A good idea would to make your app more modular. Break it up using more classes, or adding extension methods. Check for code that you repeat that can be put into one method.

Comment: Wait 'til you have a lot of code to worry about...

Comment: 1500? pfffft... Just wait..

Comment: Follow SOLID principles, separate your concerns (UI vs. business logic), Don't Repeat Yourself, refactor 'til you drop. Those should get you to methods and classes that aren't mega-monolithic.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Thank you :) These comments are actually making me laugh.. i know it will get worse, i've only done like 10% of it

Comment: [Sorites paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_the_heap) - is 1500 lines heap of code? 10000? 100000? :)...

Comment: @CésarAmorim I hoped that would brighten your day!

Comment: @tympaniplayer yes yes, i'm not repeating the same things, i've been using methods to compact code and repeat only the method where needed. I'm studying structural engineering, i'm not exactly confortable with everything in c#, breaking up into several classes would be pretty complex for what i need in this moment

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer What do you mean by refactor?

Comment: @CésarAmorim sorry, I should have said "extract until you drop". It's one tool in the arsenal of refactoring. The classic article is by "Uncle Bob" Martin: https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop

Comment: @CésarAmorim: refactoring your code to use classes will actually decrease complexity and maitainability.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes.. lol how big is too big? Nice one

Comment: Regions aren't really the best way to organize your code.  Make more classes or methods or whatever as makes sense.  More classes will not be "more complex" than region soup in one "God object" (this is a pretty widely known antipattern you could read up on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part personal preference, but one can use CTRL+M, CTRL+L to collapse/expand everything to keep things a bit more compact.

Or, through the selector (top-right side of the editor window) you can go straight to a method.

Or (again), the good old `Go to definition` (F12)

Comment: ctrl m ctrl l is very usefull, thanks, i don't have a editor window anyways, and it's not like i can show up one, it only has properties / solution explorer @Alex

Comment: I've found it, its a tiny little bar

Answer (score 1):

I usually use comments if there's a lot of code in a single file and just ctrl-f to whatever I'm looking for or when applicable I break things up into class files

Comment: that's pretty much what i've been using, thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Try not to keep too much in a single file. Regions are great, but it's even better to avoid the need for them. There is a lot of dogma around "maximum number of lines in a file/class", but all you need to know is, if the file starts getting annoying to read, you need to try and split it up :)

ALways try to describe and name your classes by their functionality. For example, you may have a ScientificCalculator class. As you start to add functions, you start to notice groups of related functionality. Once they go beyond say, 2-3 functions, move them out into new classes!

So your ScientificCalculator class may now refer to smaller classes like BasicOperations, TrigonometricOperations, LogarithmicOperations, etc... you get the picture.

There are many advantages to this, including, but not limited to, easily finding your way around your code. Oh, you want to modify the Sine() function? You know exactly where to look - the TrigonometricOperations class! And that's a much more enjoyable experience in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have 1500 lines of code in your entire project?  Or 1500 lines in a single class?  Or (much, much worse) in a single method?

1500 lines for a given project isn't so bad, provided that you've logically broken out your dependencies.  1500 for one class is probably way more than you want to manage.

When writing your classes, try to keep in mind what the class is responsible for.  Is it doing to much?  Are all the methods related to a single responsiblity?  Does it mix things like logic and database interaction?  Does it mix presentation logic with business logic?

And if it's 1500 lines of code for a single method, well...

Also, keep in mind that everything in this response should be prefaced with "In general" - there are no strictly prescriptive statements anyone can make about your code without actually seeing it, and there are always special cases.

Finally, if refactoring into separate classes seems like a large effort now, keep in mind that it will only become more and more difficult as your project grows in size and complexity.

Comment: yes the main class actually manages logic, some database interaction, etc.. However i've been managing to put it to work flawlessly, but i don't know how much more i will be able to put up to.. I'm not really confortable with classes at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tip that is a bit more controversial than others...

I'll assume the code is not directly under your control, say a legacy set of libraries or web site you inherited instead of designed...  If this is not the case then there are much better options as already suggested by others (DRY, Encapsulate, Refactor, etc, etc, etc).  However one stop-gap measure that has worked for me in the past is to make use of partial classes.

-----SuperBigClass.cs-----
    class SuperBigClass {
      public void MethodA(){
      }

```
  public void MethodB(){
  }

  public void MethodC(){
  }

  ...

  public void MethodZZTop(){
  }
}
```

....can be separated into a couple smaller files....

```
-----SuperBigClass - Methods A through Z .cs -----
public partial SuperBigClass {

  public void MethodA(){
  }

  ...

  public void MethodZ(){
  }
}

-----SuperBigClass - MethodZZTop.cs -----
public partial SuperBigClass {

  public void MethodZZTop(){
  }

}
```

As long as the term partial is applied to the class definition of all class files and all class definitions are in the same namespace this will work just fine.  Here's a link for more info: [Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Again...  The best approach is to DRY up code, encapsulate, refactor, etc, etc, etc...  but sometimes when you hop into a legacy app and you need to restructure the files themselves without making any functional changes, this shortcut (admittedly an unintended use of the partial class syntax) can be helpful for cutting large files up and helping to make sense of things.

Comment: why is it controversial?

Comment: Some developers don't like splitting classes using partials and insisting there are better methods of refactor.  Which there are.  However, in the real world, we developers don't always have weeks to refactor something.  The partial methodology outlined can help organize code cheaply as a stop gap to later refactoring.  It's not an end to itself though.